# Rails Javascript - refresh partial in view on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

In my project I am calling a partial in my view

**game_player_main.html.erb:**

```
<%= button_to "Wurfbild", home_player_statistic_detail_path(:game_id => @game.id, :player_id => @player.id, :home_or_away => @home_or_away, :player_mode => 'GoalArea'), class: 'btn_submit', :remote => true %>
```

**player_statistic_detail.js.erb:**

```
$("#player_statistic_detail").html("<%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'home/player_statistic_detail.html.erb', :handlers => [:erb]) %>");
```

Everything works fine. In my partial view I have a canvas field. By clicking this field it should reload the partial passing the x- and y-coordinates of the click event.

Here is my code:

**_player_statistic_detail.html.erb:**

```
<script>

var canvas = createHiDPICanvas(350, 228);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);

function doMouseDown(event) {
  canvas_x = event.pageX;
  canvas_y = event.pageY;

  canvas_x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  canvas_y -= canvas.offsetTop;

  $("#player_statistic_detail").html("<%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'home/player_statistic_detail.html.erb', :handlers => [:erb]) %>");

}
```

If I just copy the javascript command into my view I am getting an error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep)

Is it possible to refresh my partial player_statistic_detail.html.erb an d pass the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be:

```
var url = "url...";
  console.log("URL: " + url);
  $.ajax(url);
```